# Network connectivity works in Windows 8 only after one restart

Tags: windows-8

We have installed 15 fresh Windows 8 in my office just before 15 days. It happens with almost everyone that on early morning whenever someone starts a PC, everything works fine except Network Connectivity for a particular PC. One day someone finds that restarting PC solves the issue, and that is the habit now! This means whenever someone finds No-Network connectivity he/she just restarts PC and everything works just fine then throughout the day!

Points to note are...

1. It happens almost everyday.
2. It happens for the day's first start-up irrespective of start-up timing.
3. It happens with almost everyone.
4. It was not the case at-all with windows 7 on same PCs just before 15 days.
5. No network / other hardware changes has been made to any client PC or server in past 4-5 months.
6. We have installed fully licensed OS in our PCs.
7. All PCs are set to download updates automatically.

My questions are...

1. Is that the case with anyone else?
2. Do we need to apply any specific hidden / manually downloadable update from Microsoft for the same?

Comment: How did you activate?

Comment: We have received a set of license keys available through microsoft's site

Comment: Let me clarify, was it via the enterprise KMS server?

Comment: It is via BizSpark

Comment: And from what I understand in the question, it's not the same PC where this is happening, right? This prob is occurring on random machines each day, right?

Comment: Yeah, happens with everyone & everyday

Comment: any host name conflicts?

Comment: I had a similar problem once and found that disabling and re-enabling the network adapter would also fix the issue; a little faster than doing a full restart, but still annoying.

Comment: @Mufasa: Not able to see any adapter when this happens

Comment: What do you mean by "Not able to see any adapter when this happens" ?

Comment: @harrymc Its like I don't have any network card / adapter inside the system (only when this happens)!

Comment: I saw other problem reports with the Windows 8 network adapter driver. You could try (1) returning to the Windows 7 drivers (2) using drivers from the manufacturer's website (if any). Take care for Windows Update not to undo this.

Comment: @harrymc 1. Collected and updated drivers from manufacturer's website.  Seems windows 8 Update don't have any issue with new driver. 2. Don't know how / if i can revert back to Windows 7's driver.

Comment: If you still have Windows 7 around, you could maybe get the driver by using [Driver Magician Lite](http://www.drivermagician.com/Lite.htm).

Comment: Don't have Windows 7 around, all are migrated to Windows 8 now

Comment: You could try downgrading one computer to 7, but I can't guarantee that the driver will work in 8 or that it will solve the problem.

Comment: We were running on Windows 7 from long without any issue till.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specific answers to the questions:

1. No
2. No

But - I had a similar issue on one PC. It had 2 network cards in it, both were recognised fine, but we were using only one. Then we removed one and for a few days the other worked fine then it started not working on the network. After one or two reboots it would start working - or sometimes delete it from device manager and then rescan for hardware changes would make it work. But it happened too often to be acceptable.

So we put the old card back in again and now both cards seem to work fine. The cards are a generic Realtek clone of some sort and a D-Link 528.

This is the only PC it is happening on. The two other Windows 8 PCs work fine. All other XP and Win7 machines are fine.

I think you're approach to this has to be slow and steady - and possibly long and painful!

Because of the number of machines it happens on it seems more network related but if all the machines are the same spec it may also be hardware related.

As a start - in no particular order:

- Uninstall & reinstall NIC cards and drivers
- See if there is are newer drivers available
- Replace with a new and different cards
- Check DHCP server settings and availability

  - eg is it only the first machine of the day to start that has the problem?
  - is the DHCP server in sleep mode and waking up "slowly"?
- Check the order of machine start-up. Is there a pattern or correlation between start order and failure?
- Other hardware that's common to the failing machines?
- If all the machines start up at the same time is there some kind of bottleneck in giving out DHCP addresses?

Plus many more I can't think of at the moment!

Comment: Tried applying new drivers by downloading same from intel's site, will have to wait for 3-4 days to see effect

Comment: Facing same problem even after applying new driver from intel's site.

Comment: Are the network cards built in? If not then try moving to another slot. If they are built in then try adding in a new, different brand, NIC - just to see what happens. Sounds like Windows just can't detect the fact that the NIC is present. Like I said... long and painful process!

Comment: Network Card is inbuilt. Although I should try adding new card but as the case is with my office PCs it will be the much official and tedious process, related to the purchase and all...

Comment: Although applying new drivers have helped a bit (requires restart on alternative days approx. FUNNY). Further looks like I may need to wait till SP-1 or any other minor update works from background. Don't have any other option to go with.

Comment: Another alternative is to leave the PCs on, once they're working ok. Just "educate" the users to log out rather than switch off. This helps with automatic updates overnight too. The days of *needing* to reboot a Win 95 machine at least once a day are long gone. This networked Win8 machine stays on pretty much all week and most weekends too and usually only gets rebooted because I hark back to the old days and feel I ought to reboot it! Obviously, sometimes a Windows update requires a reboot. Otherwise I'm out of options.

Comment: Have you installed all updates? Does this problem still persist?

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the Power Management for the network cards. I had a similar issue and after removing it, the problem was solved.
My problem was a bit different because the wire was not connected and everything seemed OK. Then you plugged the wire, but the PC did not detect the network until the PC was restarted the network. The network card seemed and everything seemed to be OK. The solution was to remove the Power Management.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem as follows:
- Control Panel
- Power Options/Choose what power buttons do/Change settings that are currently unavailable/De-select "Turn on fast start-up".

Fixed my LAN connection problems and I can't pick the difference in star tup time.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a problem with the driver in Windows 8. I saw other problem reports with the Windows 8 network adapter driver.

You could try :

- Returning to the Windows 7 drivers
- Using drivers from the manufacturer's website (if any).

As a general remark: One should never migrate to a new Windows version before service-pack 1
comes out.

But as this was done here, your options if no driver version solves your problem are:

- Wait for service-pack 1 of Windows 8, hoping that it fixes the problem, and keep on rebooting
  whenever the problem occurs
- Downgrade all computers to Windows 7 and wait, testing before returning again to Windows 8
- Replace the network cards with ones known to work with Windows 8 (no idea which ones)

Comment: I think I should wait till SP-1 or any other minor update works from background. Don't have any other option to go with

Comment: I would also try to report the problem, if you have any kind of support by Microsoft, or see [this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj591516).